# Dont show sidebar on a specific page

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How I can : 
Don't open the drawerNavigator on a specific page ?

```
  Connexion: {
    screen: Connexion,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: () => null,
    }
  },
```

[I can open my sidebar here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV4is.jpg)